# Try to calculate EWMA on S&P500, but error in " Error in `[.xts`(x, i, which.i = TRUE) : subscript out of bounds "

Tags: r

I try to use calculate the EWMA on S&P500 base on the close price.
I got the daily return data and I wrote the coding like this:

```r
    sigma.ewma=function(r,lambda) {
      v=r[1]^2
      for (i in 2:length(r)) {
        v[i]=lambda*v[i-1]+(1-lambda)*r[i-1]^2
        }
      return(sqrt(v))
      }
```

And then I do

```
sigma.ewma(r.0.94)
```

But it continue shows me the error on

> Error in '[.xts'(x, i, which.i = TRUE) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: hi, can you post the output of `dput(head(r))` inside your question?

Comment: hi! thank you for your attention, the output is structure(c(0.01, -0.0398913290273013, 0.00178731057409554, -0.0162019745762807, 
0.0564523771975782, 0.00342466088136373), .indexTZ = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1554704353.16849, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), index = structure(c(946857600, 946944000, 947030400, 
947116800, 947203200, 947462400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "SPY.Close"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that R does not know that `v` will be a vector because you define `v`as the first component of `r` squared. Hence, R thinks that `v` has just one element and the problem arises when you try to access `v[2]` inside the loop.

Try this:

```
sigma.ewma=function(r, lambda) {
  v <- r
  v[1] <- r[1]^2
  for (i in 2:length(r)) {
    v[i]=lambda*v[i-1]+(1-lambda)*r[i-1]^2
  }
  return(sqrt(v))
}

sigma.ewma(r, 0.94)
            SPY.Close
2000-01-03 0.01000000
2000-01-04 0.01000000
2000-01-05 0.01376514
2000-01-06 0.01335298
2000-01-07 0.01354083
2000-01-10 0.01906738
```